# OrientationListener for Gluon

Tags: javafxports, gluon, gluon-mobile, gluon-desktop

Some Questions to Orientations with Gluon:

**Can you detect an Orientation switch with Gluon?**
*My current way of detecting is a size listener on the GlassPane, which is not ideal.*

**Can have two different FXML/Views per Orientation?**
*Normal switching when the orientation changes = easy*
**BUT**

- what about switching to the correct view when switchView() is called e.g. from NavigationDrawer? (switchView cannot be overriden since it is final...)
- starting the app in landscape mode cannot be handled in any nice way, can it?

The best way would be if Gluon supported View switching dependant on orientation on their own (just implement it in the switchView method).

Comment: Definitely Orientation improvements are on the roadmap: Providing an `orientationProperty()` so you can listen to changes in orientation and react properly (either changing the view or just modifying its layout) and also coercing portrait or landscape mode should be possible.

Comment: @JoséPereda Thank you for your answer. I'll look forward to it :)